# CSS for Braintree Hosted Fields

Tags: html, css, border, braintree

First off, I'm not that great with CSS/HTML design stuff, just the basics.

I'm using Braintree hosted fields, just wondering how to fix this using CSS or applying style's in html?

[image]

As you can see the border widths are far too big. How do I make these smaller?

For each input box i've used:

```
            <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
            <div class="hosted-field" id="card-number"></div>
```

my CSS for the fields looks like

```
#card-number {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 160ms;
  transition: border-color 160ms;
}

#card-number.braintree-hosted-fields-focused {
  border-color: #777;
}
```

These are styles taken from braintree's documentation so I'm a little confused as to why they look like the image above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adjust the height of the divs containing your hosted fields. You're able to accomplish this by adding a `height` property in your CSS like so:

```
.hosted-field {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the borders are coming from the divs themselves (you can use Chrome Web Developer Tools to determine this), you can use the following CSS rule.

```
.hosted-field {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Replace 1px with any measurement you would like.

Comment: I have done this, that's just the thickness of the line is it not? see edited version for my CSS

Comment: Are you referring to the width of the box and its contents? If so, you could use a property like `width` or `max-width`.